# Post on the wall of a Page in Facebook from a Mobile Website

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a mobile website and a button inside it. On clicking on that button , a static text will be posted on the wall of a predefined facebook page, on the behalf of currently logged-in user.If no user is logged in then a login window will be displayed and as soon as the user logs in , the same static text will be posted on the wall of the page.

How can I do it ? I tried using graph api, but all.js is required for that and it cannot be found. Other methods require access tokens and those are available for a facebook application only. Can this be done through some url ?

Comment: Cool. So what is the question?

Comment: How can I do it ? I tried using graph api, but all.js is required for that and it cannot be found. Other methods require access tokens and those are available for a facebook application only. Can this be done through some url ?